# How to create procedure with the same WHERE column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I create one procedure and the `WHERE` column is the same?

The `WHERE` column is `QuotationNo`

This is the procedure signature:

```
create procedure (QUO1 int, QUO2 int, QUO3 int, QUO4 int)
```

Output:

```
Quote     price     quantity
---------------------------------
1234       2000        1000
5678       2500        4000
9012        3000        4500 
3456        1000        1000
```

Thanks,

Captain16

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you're trying to do / what problem you're trying to solve. Can you show us the **complete** procedure (not just the signature of it) and explain in more detail, **what** you want to do with the `WHERE` clause and the `QuotationNo` column?

Comment: I'm guessing that what you are after is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause - however, if you let us know the `result` you are looking for then we will be able to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NameMyProc
    @QUO1 int, @QUO2 int, @QUO3 int, @QUO4 int
AS
    select quote, price, quantity
     from tbl
    where quotationno in (@qu01, @qu02, @qu03, @qu04)
GO
```

You can also create a table-valued function which would be a lot more flexible, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NameMyFunction (
    @QUO1 int, @QUO2 int, @QUO3 int, @QUO4 int
) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    select quote, price, quantity
     from tbl
    where quotationno in (@qu01, @qu02, @qu03, @qu04)
GO

-- Example usage:
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameMyFunction(1234, 5678, 9012, 3456) T
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving quo value in runtime

```
create proc [test]
 (QUO int(11))
as 
begin
select quote,price,quantity from table where quote=@QUO 
end
```